# Problems with ostream

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm working in a Big Integer implementation in C++ and I'm trying to use cout with my BigInt class. I already overloaded the << operator but it doesn't work in some cases.

Here is my code:

```
inline std::ostream& operator << (ostream &stream, BigInt &B){

    if (!B.getSign()){
        stream << '-';
    }
    stream << B.getNumber();

    return stream;
}
```

The code above works with:

```
c = a + b;
cout << c << endl;
```

But fails with:

```
cout << a + b << endl;
```

In the first case the program runs fine, but in the second the compiler gave an error:

```
main.cc: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
```

It's possible to overload the << operator for function in both cases?

Methods:

```
string getNumber ();
bool getSign ();

string BigInt::getNumber (){
  return this->number;
}

bool BigInt::getSign (){
  return this->sign;
}
```

Comment: The error seems a bit off, but you can't bind a temporary `BigInt` to a non-const reference. Make it a const reference; you don't need to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chris already pointed out in comments very quickly (as usual), you have a temporary created in here:

```
cout << a + b << endl;
```

You cannot bind that to a non-const reference. You will need to change the signature of your operator overloading by adding the const keyword to the reference.

This code works for me with a dummy BigInt implementation (as you have not shared yours):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BigInt
{
    public:
    bool getSign() const { return true; }
    int getNumber() const { return 0; }
    const BigInt operator+(const BigInt &other) const {}
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (ostream &stream, const BigInt &B){
//                                                 ^^^^^
    if (!B.getSign()){
        stream << '-';
    }
    stream << B.getNumber();

    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    BigInt a, b, c;
    c = a + b;
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << a + b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But yeah, I agree that the error message is not self-explanatory in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting ths error now:
bigint.h:64:17: error: passing ‘const BigInt’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool BigInt::getSign()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Guilherme: you are having a const object that is using a non-const method. That is bad. Please either make getSign const, or use mutable for variables it changes if feasible, or create a non-const BigInt there. See the const modifiers for my get methods which are missing for yours.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I was declaring the method in a wrong way.
bool getSign const () -> bool getSign() const.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
inline std::ostream& operator << (ostream &stream, BigInt &B){
```

to

```
inline std::ostream& operator << (ostream &stream, BigInt const& B){
```

`c` can be a used where `BiInt&` is expected but `a+b` cannot be because `a+b` is a temporary. But it can be used where `BigInt const&` is expected.